# jibx how to bind collection

Tags: xml, marshalling, jibx

I need to map the following XML string to an object using Jibx:

```
<Domains>
  <DomainName>fdfsdfdsfds</DomainName>
  <DomainName>fdfsdfdsfds</DomainName>
  <DomainName>fdfsdfdsfds</DomainName>
</Domains>
```

I think the following class maps the above:

```
public class Domains{
     List<String> domainNames;
}
```

I cant seem to get this to map correctly using Jibx. Does anyone know how to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

The JiBX documentation explains how to use collections here:
[Working with collections](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/tutorial/binding-collects.html).
Your problem is probably in your binding definition file.
The collection definition in your binding.xml file should read like this:

```
<collection name="DomainName" field="domainNames"/>
```